# improving breadth first logic

Tags: java, logic, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

I had an assignment a while back. After my professor graded it, he left a comment in the code that said, "simplify logic". He didn't take off any points, but I can't see another way to approach it...what I have makes sense to me, and works. So, could someone tell me a way to improve what I have? Just so I know...

```
    public void breadthFirstTraversal(){
        breadthFirstTraversal(root);
    }

    private void breadthFirstTraversal(TreeNode<E> node){

        Queue<TreeNode<E>> queue = new LinkedList<>();

        queue.add(node);

        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            TreeNode<E> temp = queue.poll();
            System.out.print(temp.data + " ");

            if(temp.left != null && temp.right == null){
                queue.add(temp.left);
            }else if(temp.left == null && temp.right != null){
                queue.add(temp.right);
            }else if(temp.left != null && temp.right != null){
                queue.add(temp.left);
                queue.add(temp.right);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`temp.right` being null has no effect on whether or not `temp.left` should be added and `temp.left` being null has no effect on `temp.right` being added. You can reduce it to just two ifs as such:

```
if( temp.left != null ) queue.add( temp.left );
if( temp.right != null ) queue.add( temp.right );
```